# I can't access an unblocked site without VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, blocking

I cant access [this](https://bys.ktu.edu.tr) site on my PC.
It is not blocked by government or any other authority.
All my friends and my phone can access this site.

Im using windows 10; using firefox, chrome, edge, int. explorer. But cant access from any of these.

I also have installed "ESET Endpoint Security" very long time ago. May this blocking me?

I also have tried to enter this site through my phone's internet on my PC. Also doesnt work.

My IP is obtained automatically. I checked it.

How can i fix my problem?

edit: I have [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PeNftryyzVg/V4TbhnC-rZI/AAAAAAAAAeI/Us9HARK9Q3Yf-R9WDiP1pQABjChbeEOkwCLcB/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2016-07-12%2Bat%2B5.28.24%2BPM.png) error after some page loading attemp (site cant be reached) on my all browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't acess" Are you getting a DNS error? HTTP error (403 forbidden, 404 Not found, 500 Internal server error, just to name a few...), a timeout?

Comment: I suspect ESET is scanning your secure HTTP traffic, and the website is configured in such a way, which conflicts with the certificate that ESET is using to use that.  Edit your question to indicate which CA signed the certificate according to your (working) configuration.  You should disable this feature and delete ALL certificates signed by ESET.  Be sure you restore your proxy configuration if it's been changed.

Comment: @milo8505 i added the error type to my question.

Comment: Have you done what I suggested?  ESET is a horrible piece of software.

Comment: @Ramhound Im trying to do what suggested. If i can figure how to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled the ESET and now i can access to blocked site. But i dont know how to use ESET and unblock that particular site at the same time. Because ESET is better than unprotected PC i think. If you make a detailed answer explaining it, then i can fix it.

Comment: The only way I could write an answer is if I were to install ESET on my system and that will never happen.  I swore off ESET software over a decade.  As I indicated, ESET was scanning your secure traffic, you can disable that feature.

Comment: @Ramhound ok thanks. i tried all settings of eset and i cant fix it. maybe ill try more settings later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed finally.

Added my site to known certifications list in [this](https://support.eset.com/en/disable-ssl-filtering-in-eset-windows-products) shown setting.